# Berry curvature for spin in a magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

Does anybody know how to compute the Berry curvature for a spin with angular momentum $s$ (so it's not the usual derivation you find for spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particles in most textbooks) in a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ pointing in an arbitrary direction and playing the role of the parameter on which the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\vec{B}\hat{\vec{S}}$ depends?

Comment: The details are in Berry's original paper:  "Quantal Phase Factors Accompanying Adiabatic Changes". Proceedings of the Royal Society A. 392 (1802): 45–57. See his equations 23 to 26.

Comment: @mikestone thanks. Do you know how I can formally include the spin rotation into the derivation rather than explaining it with words as done in this paper?